# MYSQL Insert Data Into Table With Foreign Key From Another Table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two tables: `book` and `borrowed_books`.

`Book` Table has `book_ID | Book Name`

`Borrowed_Books` has `student_ID | Book Name`

The Book names from both tables are Indexed.

I added the values of Book Table into an HTML Form select/option and it is being read but the problem is when I'm trying to insert the value, it's not reading the option name or value.

**HTML:**

```
<select id="heard" class="form-control">
<option value="">Choose Book</option>
 <?php require_once '../mysql/bookssql.php';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
   echo '<option name="borrow_book" value="'.$row['Title'].'">' .$row['Title']. '</option>';
  }
 ?>
</select>
```

**PHP Insert Code:**

```
<?php $borrow_book = $_POST['borrow_book'];
 $upload = "INSERT INTO `borrowed_books` (`student_ID`, `Book Name`) VALUES ('23, '$borrow_book');";
?>
```

Comment: The foreign key should be the book ID, not the book name.

Comment: `'23,` has an extra quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name should be in the `<select>` element, not the `<option>`s.

```
<select id="heard" name="borrow_book" class="form-control">
<option value="">Choose Book</option>
 <?php require_once '../mysql/bookssql.php';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
   echo '<option value="'.$row['Title'].'">' .$row['Title']. '</option>';
  }
 ?>
</select>
```

You have a typo in `$upload`, there's an extra `'` before `23`.

You should stop substituting variables directly into query strings, and use prepared statements with parameters. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)